# How to make an array of Foreign Keys in Django - Postgresql

Tags: python, arrays, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to figure out how can I add an array of foreign keys in Django and Postgresql.

Basically my goal is to be able to assign multiple category to any product.

My Postgres table for the `Category` field looks like this:

```
(Id, Name)

(1, 'Adventure')
(2, 'Family')
```

And the `Product` table is structured like this:

```
(Id, Title, Slug, Description, Image, Category_id)

(95678, 'My Title', 'my-title', 'Lorem Ipsum ahgdg iahdid iahdia duaw', 'www.dummyimage.com/600x500/ffff', 1)
```

Now I can't find a way to add multiple value (ids) inside of the Category_id field like this without getting an error:

```
(Id, Title, Slug, Description, Image, Category_id)

(95678, 'My Title', 'my-title', 'Lorem Ipsum ahgdg iahdid iahdia duaw', 'www.dummyimage.com/600x500/ffff', array[1, 2])
```

So how can I possibly solve this? I've tried replacing the `ForeignKey` field with an `ArrayField` and even with a `ManytoManyField` but still not working.

My code looks like this currently:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls.base import reverse



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    image = models.ImageField(default='')

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', default='', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your biggest problem is that your `category` field has the same `related_name` argument. Make it a `ManyToManyField` again, and change the `related_name` to something else.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just changed it according to your comment and now there's a new table that has been created with the name of  search_product_category and it generated 3 columns: (id, Product_id, Category_id), the original search_category table is still there with the same colums in it, so I'm not quite sure what should I do next?

Comment: "Now I can't find a way to add *multiple value(s)* inside of column `x`". In general terms, you shouldn't do that in relational databases. Use a new (third) table to store the many to many relationships. That is the `ManyToManyField` option you considered (in Django).

Comment: Thank you for the response I appreciate it! I'm still new to Postgresql so how can I do this?

Comment: If you look into section 6.15 Models from the Django Manual, it has an example with users, groups and permissions.

Comment: @progmatico Thanks so much, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I couldn't find the 6.15 section, are you talking about passing a throught argument like this? `name = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='Membership')`

Comment: Use a m2m field on your `Product` model: `categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="products")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally made it work! Now the problem is that when I try to print out the category that a product is related to in my templates like this: `<div class="text-center">
          <span class="label label-info">{{result.object.category}}</span>
      </div>` I'm getting this output: `search.Category.None` instead of the actual name of the category. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to show us your view, because I don't know where your `result.object.category` is coming from.

Comment: The views look like this: `class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):

    form_class = FacetedProductSearchForm
    template_name = 'search_result.html'
    paginate_by = 6
    context_object_name = 'object_list'`